# Complexity of brute force GCD algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, greatest-common-divisor

To complete task: find gcd(a,b) for integers a>b>0

Consider an algorithm that checks all of the numbers up to b and keeps track of the max number that divides a and b.  It would use the % operator twice per check (for a and b).  What would the complexity of this algorithm be?

I have not yet taken any formal CS courses in complexity theory (I will soon) so I am just looking for a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo operation is implemented in hardware, and it's pseudo `O(1)`. Strictly speaking, it is not constant, but it depends on the number of bits of `a` and `b`. However, even then the number of bits is the same for all input sizes, so we usually ignore this factor.

The worst-case complexity of brute force GCD is just `O(n)` (also `O(a)`, `O(b)`, or `O(min(a,b))`; they're all the same), and it happens when when the GCD is either `1`, `a`, or `b`.